How to automatically detect online users if user lost connection using websocket
Normally, I'm using react js for client and nodejs for the server and then I'm trying to do a logic on then server that detect if user leave online even if he lost his connection.
Client:
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SOCKET_URL from "../commponnents/Ulilis/Socket";
import { useAuth } from "../provider/authProvider";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const SocketContext = createContext();

export const useSocket = () => useContext(SocketContext);

export const SocketProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(navigator.onLine); // Suivre l'état de la connexion Internet

  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = user?.user?._id;

    const connectSocket = () => {
      if (userId) {
        // Utilisez l'identifiant d'utilisateur dans l'URL du WebSocket
        const newSocket = new WebSocket(`${SOCKET_URL}?userId=${userId}`);

        newSocket.onopen = () => {
          console.log("WebSocket connected");
          const initBrowser = JSON.stringify({
            type: "init connection",
            sender: userId,
            receiver: userId,
            currentbrowser: ""
          });

          newSocket.send(initBrowser);
          setSocket(newSocket);
        };

        newSocket.onclose = () => {
          console.log("WebSocket disconnected");
        };

        newSocket.onerror = (error) => {
          console.log("WebSocket error: ", error);
        };

        return newSocket;
      }
    };

    if (isConnected && userId) {
      const socketInstance = connectSocket();

      return () => {
        if (socketInstance) {
          socketInstance.close();
        }
      };
    }
  }, [user, isConnected]); // Ajouter isConnected comme dépendance

  // Gestion des événements de connexion Internet
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOnline = () => {
      console.log("Connexion Internet rétablie");
      toast.warning("Connexion Internet rétablie", {
        position: "bottom-center",
        autoClose: 5000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
        theme: "light",
      });
      setIsConnected(true); // Marquer comme connecté
    };

    const handleOffline = () => {
      console.log("Connexion Internet perdue");
      toast.warning("Connexion Internet perdue", {
        position: "bottom-center",
        autoClose: 5000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
        theme: "light",
      });
      setIsConnected(false); // Marquer comme déconnecté
      if (socket) {
        socket.close(); // Fermer la connexion WebSocket lorsqu'il n'y a pas d'Internet
        console.log("===================la fonction est xecute-================")
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("online", handleOnline);
    window.addEventListener("offline", handleOffline);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("online", handleOnline);
      window.removeEventListener("offline", handleOffline);
    };
  }, [socket]);

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
      {children}
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};


That context try to connect user if he enter on fist time in the app
And Its keep watching if user lost connection to notify that connection was lost or not

The problem is if it detects that the connection was lost, it tries to execute this
if (socket) {
        socket.close(); // Fermer la connexion WebSocket lorsqu'il n'y a pas d'Internet
        console.log("===================la fonction est xecute-================")
      }

but the truth is socket.close() function can not reach the server because also needs a connection.
Server:
const WebSocket = require("ws");
function removeCircularReferences() {
    const seen = new WeakSet();
    return function (key, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
            if (seen.has(value)) {
                return undefined;  // Supprime la référence circulaire
            }
            seen.add(value);
        }
        return value;
    };
}

class WebSocketServer {
    static instance;

    constructor() {
        if (WebSocketServer.instance) {
            return WebSocketServer.instance;
        }
        WebSocketServer.instance = this;

        this.userConnections = new Map();
    }

    saveConnections(userId, ws, browser) {
        if (this.userConnections.has(userId)) {
            const existingConnections = this.userConnections.get(userId);
            existingConnections.push({ ws, browser });
        } else {
            this.userConnections.set(userId, [{ ws, browser }]);
        }
    }

    deleteConnection(userId, ws) {
        if (this.userConnections.has(userId)) {
            const remainingConnections = this.userConnections.get(userId).filter(conn => conn.ws !== ws);
            if (remainingConnections.length > 0) {
                this.userConnections.set(userId, remainingConnections);
            } else {
                this.userConnections.delete(userId);
            }
        }
    }

    getConnections(userId) {
        return this.userConnections.get(userId) || [];
    }

    sendDataToUserConnections(receiver, sender, data, browserSet) {
        const receiverConnections = this.getConnections(receiver);
        const senderConnections = this.getConnections(sender);
        const { receivedMessage } = JSON.parse(data);
        if (receivedMessage.type !== "typing") {
            if (receivedMessage.type !== "init connection") {//if is not typing socket
                if (senderConnections.length > 1) {
                    senderConnections.forEach(({ ws, browser }) => {
                        if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN && browser !== browserSet) {
                            ws.send(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        if (receivedMessage.type === "init connection") { //if is init connection
            if (senderConnections.length > 0) {
                senderConnections.forEach(({ ws, browser }) => {
                    if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN && browser === browserSet) {
                        let modifyData = JSON.parse(data)
                        modifyData.receivedMessage.currentbrowser = browserSet
                        ws.send(JSON.stringify(modifyData));
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        if (receiverConnections.length > 0) {

            receiverConnections.forEach(({ ws }) => {
                if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN && receiver !== sender) {
                    ws.send(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    dispatchOnlineUsers() {
        const onlineUsers = Array.from(this.userConnections.keys()).map(userId => ({
            userId,
            connections: this.userConnections.get(userId)
        }));

        if (onlineUsers.length > 0) {
            onlineUsers.forEach(({ connections }) => {
                connections.forEach(({ ws }) => {
                    if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                        // Vérifie si la structure est circulaire avant de l'envoyer
                        try {
                            const message = {
                                receivedMessage: {
                                    type: "online",
                                    data: onlineUsers
                                }
                            };

                            // Tente de sérialiser les données en JSON
                            const jsonString = JSON.stringify(message, removeCircularReferences());

                            // Si la sérialisation est réussie, envoie le message
                            ws.send(jsonString);
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error("Circular structure detected, message not sent.", error);
                            // Si une erreur survient, l'envoi est ignoré
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }

    initialize(server) {
        const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

        wss.on("connection", (ws, req) => {
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(req.url.replace("/?", ""));
            const userId = urlParams.get("userId");
            const browser = req.headers["sec-websocket-key"];

            this.saveConnections(userId, ws, browser);
            this.dispatchOnlineUsers();

            console.log("Nouvelle connexion WebSocket pour l'utilisateur avec l'ID:", userId);

            ws.on("message", (message) => {
                if (Buffer.isBuffer(message)) {
                    message = message.toString("utf8");
                }
                const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message);
                const { receiver, sender } = parsedMessage;
                const response = JSON.stringify({ receivedMessage: parsedMessage });

                this.sendDataToUserConnections(receiver, sender, response, browser);
            });
            setInterval(() => {
                this.dispatchOnlineUsers();
            }, 10000);
            ws.on("close", () => {
                console.log("Connexion WebSocket fermée pour l'utilisateur avec l'ID:", userId);
                this.deleteConnection(userId, ws);
                this.dispatchOnlineUsers();
            });
        });
        return wss;
    }

    static getWebSocketServer() {
        if (!WebSocketServer.instance) {
            throw new Error("WebSocketServer instance has not been initialized.");
        }
        return WebSocketServer.instance;
    }
}

const initializeWebSocketServer = (server) => {
    return new WebSocketServer().initialize(server);
};

module.exports = {
    initializeWebSocketServer,
    getWebSocketServer: WebSocketServer.getWebSocketServer,
    sendDataToUserConnections: (receiver, sender, data, browserSet) => {
        const server = WebSocketServer.getWebSocketServer();
        server.sendDataToUserConnections(receiver, sender, data, browserSet);
    }
};

